Mysql enum: can't update or insert in the table, getting 'Data truncated' error
This is my table:
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `productID` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `designID` bigint DEFAULT '0',
  `qualityID` bigint DEFAULT '0',
  `brandName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `brandNameId` bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `brandCounter` int NOT NULL,
  `productName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mainCategoryId` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `subCategoryId` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `setConfiguration` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `isCombo` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `description` text,
  `isLeather` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `isCutSizeAvailable` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `soleType` varchar(35) DEFAULT NULL,
  `moqPairs` int NOT NULL,
  `moqSets` int NOT NULL,
  `minLeadTime` int NOT NULL,
  `maxLeadTime` int NOT NULL,
  `price` double(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `sellerPrice` double(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `transferPrice` double(15,6) DEFAULT '0.000000',
  `margin` double(8,4) NOT NULL,
  `marginAmt` double(7,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `tax` double(8,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `taxAmt` double(7,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `tcs` double(5,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0100',
  `tcsAmt` double(7,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `transferValue` double(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `skPrice` double(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `warrenty` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `defImage` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `sellerID` int NOT NULL,
  `parseID` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdOn` int NOT NULL,
  `updatedOn` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `setSizes` varchar(16) DEFAULT '8',
  `styleTag` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `matUpper` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `matInsock` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `matLining` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `matHeel` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mrp` double(10,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `searchKeywords` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subSellerId` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `isChangeRequested` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `changeRequestedOn` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `isSKAssured` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sizeChartID` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastApprovedOn` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `alterationMessage` text,
  `alterationStatus` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `soleTypeId` bigint DEFAULT '0',
  `isSubmitted` int DEFAULT '0',
  `submittedOn` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `isApproved` int DEFAULT '0',
  `hidden` int NOT NULL,
  `approvedOn` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `isRejected` int DEFAULT '0',
  `rejectedOn` int DEFAULT '0',
  `rejectedRemarks` text,
  `hsnCode` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `styleTagID` bigint DEFAULT '0',
  `taxOnMargin` double(8,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `taxOnMarginAmt` double(8,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `lotSize` int NOT NULL,
  `sellsType` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sizeStandard` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `cartonType` int NOT NULL,
  `multipleColors` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `limitedCartonStatus` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `limitedCarton` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `leadTime` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `weight` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `packaging` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `imported` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `productDescription` text,
  `platform` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `countryOrigin` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0=> Draft 1=>Approved 2=>InReview 3=>InApprovedReview 4=>Removed',
  `currentStage` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `currentStageValue` json DEFAULT (json_object()),
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `gradeID` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `designType` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdBy` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdByType` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `productOwner` enum('BRAND','BRAND_AGGREGATOR_GRADE','BRAND_AGGREGATOR_DESIGN','BRAND_TRADING') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`productID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `CompositeKey` (`brandNameId`,`brandCounter`),
  KEY `sellerID` (`sellerID`),
  KEY `isApproved` (`isApproved`),
  KEY `approvedOn` (`approvedOn`),
  KEY `brandNameId` (`brandNameId`),
  KEY `skPrice` (`skPrice`),
  KEY `soleTypeId` (`soleTypeId`),
  KEY `styleTagID` (`styleTagID`),
  KEY `brandName` (`brandName`,`brandCounter`),
  KEY `brandName_2` (`brandName`),
  KEY `brandCounter` (`brandCounter`),
  KEY `sellsType` (`sellsType`),
  KEY `moqPairs` (`moqPairs`,`isApproved`,`approvedOn`),
  KEY `brandCounter_2` (`brandCounter`,`moqPairs`,`isApproved`,`approvedOn`,`sellsType`),
  KEY `productID_2` (`productID`,`isApproved`,`approvedOn`),
  KEY `productID` (`productID`,`sellerID`,`isApproved`,`approvedOn`,`brandNameId`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `brandNameId_2` (`brandNameId`,`sellerID`),
  KEY `brandNameId_3` (`brandNameId`,`sellerID`,`isApproved`,`approvedOn`),
  KEY `mainCategoryId` (`mainCategoryId`),
  KEY `subCategoryId` (`subCategoryId`),
  KEY `hid_ix` (`hidden`),
  KEY `grade_index` (`gradeID`),
  KEY `created_by_index` (`createdBy`),
  KEY `updatedOnIdx` (`updatedOn`),
  KEY `updatedAtidx` (`updated_at`),
  KEY `designTypeIdx` (`designType`),
  KEY `design_index` (`designID`),
  KEY `quality_index` (`qualityID`),
  KEY `productName_index` (`productName`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `product_name_idx` (`productName`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2066613 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;

I added 'BRAND_TRADING' in the enum in productOwner col but on inserting or updating any row (other than the original values) I am getting this:
(pymysql.err.DataError) (1265, \"Data truncated for column 'productOwner' at row 1\")\n[SQL: INSERT INTO products (`designID`, `qualityID`, `brandName`, `brandNameId`, `brandCounter`, `productName`, `mainCategoryId`, `subCategoryId`, `setConfiguration`, `isCombo`, description, `isLeather`, `isCutSizeAvailable`, `soleType`, `moqPairs`, `moqSets`, `minLeadTime`, `maxLeadTime`, price, `sellerPrice`, `transferPrice`, margin, `marginAmt`, tax, `taxAmt`, tcs, `tcsAmt`, `transferValue`, `skPrice`, warrenty, `defImage`, `sellerID`, `parseID`, `createdOn`, `updatedOn`, `setSizes`, `styleTag`, `matUpper`, `matInsock`, `matLining`, `matHeel`, mrp, `searchKeywords`, `subSellerId`, `isChangeRequested`, `changeRequestedOn`, `isSKAssured`, `sizeChartID`, `lastApprovedOn`, `alterationMessage`, `alterationStatus`, `soleTypeId`, `isSubmitted`, `submittedOn`, `isApproved`, hidden, `approvedOn`, `isRejected`, `rejectedOn`, `rejectedRemarks`, `hsnCode`, `styleTagID`, `taxOnMargin`, `taxOnMarginAmt`, `lotSize`, `sellsType`, `sizeStandard`, `cartonType`, `multipleColors`, `limitedCartonStatus`, `limitedCarton`, `leadTime`, weight, packaging, imported, `productDescription`, platform, `countryOrigin`, status, `currentStage`, `currentStageValue`, `createdBy`, `designType`, `createdByType`, `productOwner`) VALUES (%(designID)s, %(qualityID)s, %(brandName)s, %(brandNameId)s, %(brandCounter)s, %(productName)s, %(mainCategoryId)s, %(subCategoryId)s, %(setConfiguration)s, %(isCombo)s, %(description)s, %(isLeather)s, %(isCutSizeAvailable)s, %(soleType)s, %(moqPairs)s, %(moqSets)s, %(minLeadTime)s, %(maxLeadTime)s, %(price)s, %(sellerPrice)s, %(transferPrice)s, %(margin)s, %(marginAmt)s, %(tax)s, %(taxAmt)s, %(tcs)s, %(tcsAmt)s, %(transferValue)s, %(skPrice)s, %(warrenty)s, %(defImage)s, %(sellerID)s, %(parseID)s, %(createdOn)s, %(updatedOn)s, %(setSizes)s, %(styleTag)s, %(matUpper)s, %(matInsock)s, %(matLining)s, %(matHeel)s, %(mrp)s, %(searchKeywords)s, %(subSellerId)s, %(isChangeRequested)s, %(changeRequestedOn)s, %(isSKAssured)s, %(sizeChartID)s, %(lastApprovedOn)s, %(alterationMessage)s, %(alterationStatus)s, %(soleTypeId)s, %(isSubmitted)s, %(submittedOn)s, %(isApproved)s, %(hidden)s, %(approvedOn)s, %(isRejected)s, %(rejectedOn)s, %(rejectedRemarks)s, %(hsnCode)s, %(styleTagID)s, %(taxOnMargin)s, %(taxOnMarginAmt)s, %(lotSize)s, %(sellsType)s, %(sizeStandard)s, %(cartonType)s, %(multipleColors)s, %(limitedCartonStatus)s, %(limitedCarton)s, %(leadTime)s, %(weight)s, %(packaging)s, %(imported)s, %(productDescription)s, %(platform)s, %(countryOrigin)s, %(status)s, %(currentStage)s, %(currentStageValue)s, %(createdBy)s, %(designType)s, %(createdByType)s, %(productOwner)s)]\n[parameters: {'designID': 0, 'qualityID': 0, 'brandName': 'test', 'brandNameId': '1001175', 'brandCounter': 53, 'productName': 'test 053', 'mainCategoryId': '1000020', 'subCategoryId': '1003447', 'setConfiguration': 1, 'isCombo': 0, 'description': None, 'isLeather': 0, 'isCutSizeAvailable': 0, 'soleType': None, 'moqPairs': 3, 'moqSets': 3, 'minLeadTime': 0, 'maxLeadTime': 0, 'price': 0, 'sellerPrice': 0, 'transferPrice': 0, 'margin': 0, 'marginAmt': '0.00', 'tax': 0, 'taxAmt': 0, 'tcs': '0.0100', 'tcsAmt': '0.00', 'transferValue': 0, 'skPrice': 0, 'warrenty': 1, 'defImage': 'https://xyz/uploadfile_1-23dfb45-d002-40f9-bdd0-030e3e329203.jpg', 'sellerID': '1490486208', 'parseID': None, 'createdOn': 1715713458, 'updatedOn': None, 'setSizes': '8', 'styleTag': None, 'matUpper': None, 'matInsock': None, 'matLining': None, 'matHeel': None, 'mrp': 0, 'searchKeywords': '', 'subSellerId': None, 'isChangeRequested': '0', 'changeRequestedOn': None, 'isSKAssured': '0', 'sizeChartID': 0, 'lastApprovedOn': None, 'alterationMessage': None, 'alterationStatus': None, 'soleTypeId': '0', 'isSubmitted': 1, 'submittedOn': 1715713458, 'isApproved': 1, 'hidden': 0, 'approvedOn': 1715713458, 'isRejected': '0', 'rejectedOn': 0, 'rejectedRemarks': None, 'hsnCode': '878776', 'styleTagID': '0', 'taxOnMargin': '0.00', 'taxOnMarginAmt': '0.00', 'lotSize': 3, 'sellsType': 1, 'sizeStandard': 1, 'cartonType': 0, 'multipleColors': 1, 'limitedCartonStatus': 0, 'limitedCarton': None, 'leadTime': None, 'weight': 0, 'packaging': '0', 'imported': '0', 'productDescription': None, 'platform': 'web', 'countryOrigin': 'India', 'status': 1, 'currentStage': 'LAUNCHED', 'currentStageValue': '{\"launched\": {\"launchedBy\": \"1490488311\", \"launchedOn\": \"2024-05-15 00:34:18.318600\"}, \"productApproved\": [{\"approvedBy\": \"1490488311\", \"approvedOn\": \"2024-05-15 00:34:18\"}]}', 'createdBy': '1490488311', 'designType': None, 'createdByType': 'Seller', 'productOwner': 'BRAND_TRADING'}]\n(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/9h9h)

I have tried following approaches based on answers for similar problems:

altering the col as VARCHAR(30) but the problem still persists (same error)
creating a new col named productOwnerNew (tried with both as VARCHAR and enum with new value) and dumping data from productOwner, here I was able to add/edit the row but when I changed the col name productOwnerNew -> productOwner and productOwner -> productOwnerOld again I was not able to add/edit col as 'BRAND_TRADING' (tried with other random strings too) and getting the same error but interestingly i was able to add/edit the now productOwnerOld col
checked the triggers, constraints, FK: no such things on the column, there was a index but i removed it just in case before taking above approaches
checked the sql_mode it is set as ''

PS:
The example I gave earlier for showing the error is via sqlAlchemy (This error is not because of SQLAlchemy), I got the same error while updating in the table directly too and i am using this:
product_record = Products(**request_data)
dbw_conn.add(product_record)
dbw_conn.flush()

and this is the request_data here:
{'sellerID': '1490486208', 'setConfiguration': 1, 'isCombo': 0, 'brandName': 'test', 'brandNameId': '1001175', 'productOwner': 'BRAND_TRADING', 'sizeStandard': 1, 'brandCounter': 53, 'productName': 'test 053', 'sellsType': 1, 'approvedOn': 1715702816, 'rejectedOn': 0, 'mainCategoryId': '1000020', 'subCategoryId': '1003447', 'lotSize': 3, 'moqPairs': 3, 'moqSets': 3, 'limitedCartonStatus': 0, 'platform': 'web', 'multipleColors': 1, 'createdOn': 1715702794, 'createdBy': '1490488311', 'createdByType': 'Seller', 'productDescription': None, 'packaging': None, 'countryOrigin': 'India', 'weight': 0, 'hsnCode': '878776', 'defImage': 'https://xyz/uploadfile_1-8unsfjl9-d002-40f9-bdd0-030e3e329203.jpg', 'sellerPrice': 0, 'price': 0, 'skPrice': 0, 'taxAmt': 0, 'tax': 0, 'transferValue': 0, 'transferPrice': 0, 'mrp': 0, 'searchKeywords': '', 'sizeChartID': 0, 'status': 1, 'isApproved': 1, 'currentStage': 'LAUNCHED', 'isSubmitted': 1, 'submittedOn': 1715702818, 'currentStageValue': {'launched': {'launchedBy': '1490488311', 'launchedOn': '2024-05-14 21:36:59.032219'}, 'productApproved': [{'approvedBy': '1490488311', 'approvedOn': '2024-05-14 21:37:00'}]}}

error via direct update in the table - Data truncated for column 'productOwner' at row 1
using a query similar to this UPDATE products p SET p.productOwner = 'BRAND_TRADING' WHERE p.productID = 1000000;

Why do you have the parameter values inside the SQL string? They should be in a separate argument from the query. Please show the Python/SQLAlchemy code.

@Barmar I am adding it using sqlAlchemy but this is just for context even when I am adding/editing directly in the table, I am getting the same error. Updating question for more context regarding same

You can't use placeholders like $(productOwner) if you execute the SQL directly.

@Barmar Please see the PS part for more clarification

Can you reproduce this with a simpler table so we don't have to scroll through dozens of columns in the code and error message?

@Barmar Not able to reproduce this in any other table, and also tried restarting the SQL instances fyi.

Can you pls add the sql statement you tried with the direct update to the question?

@Shadow using a query similar to this UPDATE products p SET p.productOwner = 'BRAND_TRADING' WHERE p.productID = 1000000;

Update, we are using triggers to store the write events done on the products table to a different table named product_logs that has a similar structure - a col named productOwner with enum values and I didn't add the new value BRAND_TRADING there. My user didn't have permission to see the triggers and because of this, I was seeing an empty response from SHOW TRIGGERS and select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TRIGGERS where EVENT_OBJECT_TABLE='products';.
